# Why dask delayed do nothing?

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

I am using `dask` to process files line by line. However, dask seems that do not do anything. My code logic is as follows:

```
import dask
from dask import delayed
from time import sleep

@dask.delayed
def inc(x):
    sleep(1)
    print(x)


def test():
    for i in range(5):
        delayed(inc)(i)

dask.compute(test())
```

However, no any outputs in console. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `test` does not return anything.

Perhaps you meant to do something like

```
def test():
    out = []
    for i in range(5):
        out.append(inc(i))
    return out
```

(note that you already decorated `inc` with `delayed`, there is no need to call `delayed(inc)` again)

Comment: So if the function does not return anythin, then dask would not run the function. Thanks, I successfully run the function!

Comment: I would rather say: you gave `compute()` nothing to do.